# Unable to fetch user location details by IP

Tags: javascript, reactjs

hello im new to react and trying to build a weather site. i have a search functionality which works, but im also trying to get the local weather for the user.

for this i get city from: https://geoip-db.com/json/

weather api: https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/

then i save that city as a variable in the state so i can use it in the api.

here is the code:
`

```
state = {
    geoipCity: "",
}

componentDidMount(){
    const geoApiUrl = "https://geoip-db.com/json/";
    fetch(geoApiUrl)

    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(geoip => {
        this.setState({ geoipCity: geoip.city })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Fetch error: " + err);
    });

    console.log("prefetch:" + this.state.geoipCity)
    const weatherApiUrl = `${api.base}weather?q=${this.state.geoipCity}&weather&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`;
    fetch(weatherApiUrl)

    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result)

        let locationOutput = document.querySelector("#locationOutput");
        if(result.cod === "404"){
            locationOutput.innerHTML = `${this.state.geoipCity} is not a valid city name`;
        }

        /*
        locationOutput.innerHTML = `
        Your live in ${this.state.geoipCity} and it feels like ${result.main.feels_like}°C`;
        */
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Fetch error: " + err);
    });   
}
```

`

so the first fetch gets the city and saves it in the geoipCity state variable. this i try to use it in the api search.
however right before that i have:

```
console.log("prefetch:" + this.state.geoipCity)
```

which shows me that this.state.geoipCity is empty.

any ideas?

EDIT: SOLVED, HERE IS THE CODE IN CASE ANYONE BENEFITS FROM IT IN THE FUTURE

`

```
componentDidMount(){
    const geoApiUrl = "https://geoip-db.com/json/";
    fetch(geoApiUrl)

    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
    console.log(result)

        this.setState({ geoipCity: result.city }, () => {
            //console.log(this.state);
            const weatherApiUrl = `${api.base}weather?q=${this.state.geoipCity}&weather&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`;
            fetch(weatherApiUrl)

            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result)

                let locationOutput = document.querySelector("#locationOutput");
                if(result.cod === "404"){
                    locationOutput.innerHTML = `${this.state.geoipCity} is not a valid city name`;
                }


                locationOutput.innerHTML = `
                Your live in ${this.state.geoipCity} and it feels like ${result.main.feels_like}°C`;

            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("Fetch error: " + err);
            });
        });

        //this.setState({ geoipCity: geoip.city })
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("Fetch error: " + err);
    });
}
```

`

Comment: I am in China this moment and I input https://geoip-db.com/json/ in my browser and I get this : {"country_code":"CN","country_name":"China","city":null,"postal":null,"latitude":34.7725,"longitude":113.7266,"IPv4":"42.245.203.150","state":null} you can notice that city is null.so please check api response to see if city is null.

Comment: @CharlieCai : That would be Zhengzhou. The problem is OP needs to reverse geocode city based on longitude/latitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.setState` is async.

You need to use the callback of setState in order to console.log the new state.

```
this.setState({ geoipCity: geoip.city }, (newState) => {
    console.log(newState);
});
```

Every `setState` will re-render the component but `componentDidMount` only executes on the first render.

Comment: this helped me. i had to write the second fetch inside of the callback. thanks!